# Issue scraping with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I've been scraping websites before using this same technique. But with this website it seems to not work.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.weatheronline.co.uk/weather/maps/current?LANG=en&DATE=1354104000&CONT=euro&LAND=UK&KEY=UK&SORT=1&INT=06&TYP=sonne&ART=tabelle&RUBRIK=akt&R=310&CEL=C"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print soup
```

In the output should be the content of the webpage but instead I am just getting this:

GIF89a (it follows also some symbols I can't copy here)

Any ideas of what the problem is and how should I proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I want to know why I am getting a gif accesing the url like that
>   and when I access it via my browser I get the website perfectly.

because these guys are smart and don't want their website to be accessed outside a web browser. What you need to do is to fake a known browser by adding User-agent to the header. Here is a modified example that will work

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> opener = urllib2.build_opener()
>>> opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
>>> url = "http://www.weatheronline.co.uk/weather/maps/current?LANG=en&DATE=1354104000&CONT=euro&LAND=UK&KEY=UK&SORT=1&INT=06&TYP=sonne&ART=tabelle&RUBRIK=akt&R=310&CEL=C"
>>> response = opener.open(url)
>>> page = response.read()
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

Comment: @Abhijit Note that as soon as they figure out you are scraping the site, they'll might just make a change to their HTML that breaks your scraping. Or block your IP address. Or any other change. They don't want you to scrape their site. Maybe you should respect that.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Answer (score 0):

It means that URL you are accessing is a GIF image, not a web page. In fact, I ran the script and saved "page" to a file, and you get a 1x1 pixel white (or possibly transparent) GIF.

The reason you don't get that with an actual web browser may in fact be because they don't want you to scrape it.

*From their terms of use: 
"You may not copy, reproduce, republish, download, post, broadcast, transmit or otherwise use the Site's content in any way except for your own personal, non-commercial use. "*

You could maybe fake a web-browser with some work, but I'd still recommend you to talk to WeatherOnline instead. They want you to pay for their data, but if you do so, you will surely get a nice API you can use instead of screen scraping.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that, but I want to know why I am getting a gif accesing the url like that and when I access it via my browser I get the website perfectly.