# web scraping and 403 forbidden: My web scraper is blocked by a website, what should I do to make request?

Tags: python, python-2.7, request, user-agent

I wrote a script to pull data from a website. But after several times, it shows 403 forbidden when I request.

What should I do for this issue.

My code is below:

```
import requests, bs4
import csv

links = []
with open('1-432.csv', 'rb') as urls:
    reader = csv.reader(urls)
    for i in reader:
        links.append(i[0])
info = []
nbr  = 1

for url in links:

    # Problem is here.
    sub = []
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup     = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    start    = soup.find('em')
    forname  = soup.find_all('b') 
    name = []


    for b in forname:
        name.append(b.text)
    name = name[7]
    sub.append(name.encode('utf-8'))
    for b in start.find_next_siblings('b'):
        if b.text in ('Category:', 'Website:', 'Email:', 'Phone' ):
            sub.append(b.next_sibling.strip().encode('utf-8'))
    info.append(sub)
    print('Page ' + str(nbr) + ' is saved')
    with open('Canada_info_4.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for u in info:
            wr.writerow(u)
    nbr += 1
```

what should I do to make requests to the website.
Example url is http://www.worldhospitaldirectory.com/dr-bhandare-hospital/info/43225

Thanks.

Comment: if you are blocked you are blocked. Most websites take a dim view of scraping. you are probably in violation of their terms of use

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really a programming question

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of different things that could be the problem, and depending on what their blacklisting policy it might be too late to fix.

At the very least, scraping like this is generally considered to be dick behavior. You're hammering their server. Try putting a `time.sleep(10)` inside your main loop.

Secondly, try setting your user agents. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720430/issue-scraping-with-beautiful-soup) or [here](http://www.markbartlett.org/web-engineering/web-engineering-1/page-scraping-with-urllib2-beautifulsoup)

A better solution though would be to see if they have an API you can use.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try.